# Is there a way to let linqpad know that a field is a primary key?

Tags: linqpad

I have a table called logs, it has a primary key but is not defined as such.

If I want to use LinqPad to update said table's data, I have to set the table to actually have a primary key.

If I was using LinqToSql within visual studio I could modify the mapping to get round this...

I would like to know if the same is possible within LinqPad so that I don't have actually change the database itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - you must define a primary key in the database. LINQPad follows convention over configuration in this respect.

The other option is to generate a typed datacontext in Visual Studio and then tell LINQPad to use that typed datacontext. After clicking Add Connection, choose 'Use a typed datacontext from your own assembly'.

Comment: It would be nice if LINQPad had some tools to build the source of a typed datacontext and modify and compile it in place of the automatic one.